# wildcard query on not analysed field returns no results

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Elastic 1.5, running on AWS.  I am trying to run the following query:

```
GET /pictures_testing/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "wildcard": {
               "aircraft_type_search.search": {
                  "wildcard": "piper"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But it returns no results.  However I can get results back from aircraft_type_search, just not aircraft_type_search.search mapping

Here's the field mappings:

```
{
   "pictures_testing": {
      "mappings": {
         "picture": {
            "aircraft_type_search": {
               "full_name": "aircraft_type_search",
               "mapping": {
                  "aircraft_type_search": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "fields": {
                        "lower_case_sort": {
                           "type": "string",
                           "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                        },
                        "search": {
                           "type": "string",
                           "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have other fields set up in the same way and the .search mapping will return results (including wildcard queries which is the ultimate point) so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this fields doesn't.

GET /pictures_testing/ returns:

```
    {
   "pictures_testing": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "picture": {
            "properties": {
               "ab_archive": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "ab_publication": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "aircraft_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "aircraft_type": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "aircraft_type_search": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "aircraft_verified": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "airport": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "airshow": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "airshow_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "airshow_verified": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "approved": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true
               },
               "category": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "code_number": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "construction_number": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "country": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "created_by": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "created_on": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "date_added": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
               },
               "date_approved": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
               },
               "date_taken": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "date_taken_formatted": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
               },
               "display_picture": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "displayed_info": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "displayteam": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "displayteam_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "displayteam_verified": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "editors_choice": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "email": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "filename": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "full_size_folder": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "group": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "hidden_email": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "hidden_photographer": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "information": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "initial": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "ip": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "location_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "location_verified": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "manufacturer": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "military_unit": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "model": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "modified_by": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "modified_on": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "operator": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "operator_category_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "operator_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "operator_type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "operator_verified": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "original_filename": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "photographer": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "picture_category_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "null_value": -1
               },
               "picture_id": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "picturecategory_verified": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "registration": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "reject_reason": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "site_name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "slug": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "subtype": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "subtype2": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "lower_case_sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                     },
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "uploaded_file_size": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "verified": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "views": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true
               },
               "website": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "year": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "ignore_malformed": true
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1487318302366",
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                  "case_insensitive_sort": {
                     "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "keyword"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "version": {
               "created": "1050299"
            },
            "uuid": "KoaR8mksTReY_2mRu4wi-Q"
         }
      },
      "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

Sample documents that should match:

```
        {
        "_index": "pictures_testing",
        "_type": "picture",
        "_id": "1328215",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "id": "1328215",
           "aircraft_id": "8947",
           "operator_id": "3273",
           "operator_category_id": "3",
           "location_id": "2877",
           "displayteam_id": null,
           "airshow_id": null,
           "picture_category_id": "4",
           "military_unit": "",
           "registration": "9M-AQJ",
           "code_number": "",
           "construction_number": "28-7125042",
           "date_taken": "9th March 1975",
           "date_taken_formatted": "1975-03-09 00:00:00",
           "year": "1975",
           "information": "A rather hazy slide being a long shot in 34c.",
           "approved": null,
           "display_picture": "yes",
           "reject_reason": "",
           "editors_choice": "no",
           "ab_publication": "",
           "ab_archive": "no",
           "correction_id": null,
           "correction_reason": null,
           "correction_status": null,
           "correction_rejection_reason": null,
           "views": "159",
           "created_on": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
           "created_by": "0",
           "modified_on": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
           "modified_by": null,
           "date_approved": "2012-01-02 18:58:07",
           "initial": "P",
           "manufacturer": "Piper",
           "type": "Piper PA-28 / 28R Cherokee",
           "model": "Piper PA-28-140 Cherokee D",
           "subtype": "Fixed Wing - Propeller",
           "subtype2": "Light Aircraft",
           "verified": "1",
           "operator": "Private",
           "operator_type": "Company",
           "airport": "Kota Kinabalu International (BKI / WBKK)",
           "country": "Malaysia",
           "deleted_on": null,
           "deleted_by": null,
           "slug": "general",
           "name": "General",
           "displayteam": null,
           "airshow": null,
           "category": "Light Aircraft",
           "group": "A",
           "picture_id": "1328215",
           "aircraft_verified": "1",
           "aircraft_type": "Piper PA-28 / 28R Cherokee",
           "operator_verified": "1",
           "location_verified": "1",
           "displayteam_verified": null,
           "airshow_verified": null,
           "picturecategory_verified": "1",
           "aircraft_type_search": "Piper PA-28 / 28R Cherokee Piper PA-28-140 Cherokee D"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "pictures_testing",
        "_type": "picture",
        "_id": "1328213",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "id": "1328213",
           "aircraft_id": "5302",
           "operator_id": "3273",
           "operator_category_id": "3",
           "location_id": "2877",
           "displayteam_id": null,
           "airshow_id": null,
           "picture_category_id": "4",
           "military_unit": "",
           "registration": "9M-ANZ",
           "code_number": "",
           "construction_number": "28-20740",
           "date_taken": "9th March 1975",
           "date_taken_formatted": "1975-03-09 00:00:00",
           "year": "1975",
           "information": "-",
           "approved": null,
           "display_picture": "yes",
           "reject_reason": "",
           "editors_choice": "no",
           "ab_publication": "yes",
           "ab_archive": "no",
           "correction_id": null,
           "correction_reason": null,
           "correction_status": null,
           "correction_rejection_reason": null,
           "views": "126",
           "created_on": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
           "created_by": "0",
           "modified_on": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
           "modified_by": null,
           "date_approved": "2012-01-02 18:56:27",
           "initial": "P",
           "manufacturer": "Piper",
           "type": "Piper PA-28 / 28R Cherokee",
           "model": "Piper PA-28-140 Cherokee",
           "subtype": "Fixed Wing - Propeller",
           "subtype2": "Light Aircraft",
           "verified": "1",
           "operator": "Private",
           "operator_type": "Company",
           "airport": "Kota Kinabalu International (BKI / WBKK)",
           "country": "Malaysia",
           "deleted_on": null,
           "deleted_by": null,
           "slug": "general",
           "name": "General",
           "displayteam": null,
           "airshow": null,
           "category": "Light Aircraft",
           "group": "A",
           "picture_id": "1328213",
           "aircraft_verified": "1",
           "aircraft_type": "Piper PA-28 / 28R Cherokee",
           "operator_verified": "1",
           "location_verified": "1",
           "displayteam_verified": null,
           "airshow_verified": null,
           "picturecategory_verified": "1",
           "aircraft_type_search": "Piper PA-28 / 28R Cherokee Piper PA-28-140 Cherokee"
        }
     },
```

Anyone know what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the real mapping you get when running: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/pictures_testing`, the one you shared doesn't seem to use the official syntax.

Comment: The aircraft_type_search.search field is "not_analyzed", so to match the query, the aircraft_type_search.search field should contain the word "piper" EXCATLY, and only that word (no other word). Are you aware of that? (just checking)

Comment: @Val added that output to the question. I'm using the sense JSON interface for elastic BTW which might explain the syntax.

Comment: @PaulinTrognon But that's the right thing to use for wildcard searches though right? Certainly works for other fields that I have set up in the same way, so 'piper*' would be a more typical query.

Comment: Can you also show a sample document that you think should match?

Comment: @Val have added 2 sample documents that should match

Comment: Ok, it is clear now that the wildcard search for `piper` cannot match `Piper`, you need to use `Piper` instead in your query. This is because the `aircraft_type_search.search` field is not analyzed.

Comment: @Val Thanks, I see that now.  See comment to answer for below for a related query to do with the registration field. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "not_analyzed" in the mapping for the field "aircraft_type_search.search". "not_analyzed" is only when you want to search for a field **exactly**, with the same case.

If you want the result "Piper PA-28 / 28R Cherokee Piper PA-28-140 Cherokee" when you search "piper" then change the mapping to:

```
  "aircraft_type_search": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
      "lower_case_sort": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
      },
      "search": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard" // CHANGE HERE
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you don't have to use the wildcard query. Just use the **match** query.

```
GET /pictures_testing/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "aircraft_type_search.search": "piper"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This will look for the word "piper" in the "aircraft_type_search" field, and will match your search.

Comment: That seems to work well for that field, however I can't then do wildcard queries.  This is particularly an issue for the registration field where a typical search may be for "G-BOA*" expecting results returned of the form "G-BOAC, G-BOAB, G-BOAR" etc.  

Is there an analyzer type that would be suitable for this sort of query that doesn't use wildcard?

If I did use wildcards is there an analyzer type that would be particularly  suitable?